# Will Ubuntu check if it can be installed on boot?

Tags: boot, 64-bit

I have 32bit Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop. I want to install 64bit Ubuntu. Seems that my processor supports x64 instructions. If 64bit cannot be installed, will Ubuntu Installer notify me if it cannot be installed when I boot from setup USB/CD?

Comment: No your system will hang or behave strangely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 64-bit installer will not proceed if it finds 32-bit only hardware.
If it works your hardware supports 64-bit instructions.

Comment: The installer would not even boot if it was not compatible with the hardware architecture.

Comment: Installer will not even print error message?

Comment: It will say something to the effect indeed. Something like wrong architecture perhaps. I cannot test it right now because I have no 32-bit hardware currently available. The other way around works, 32-bit OS in a 64-bit capable hardware, so it doesn't show any error.